# How do i enable line breaks in php?

Tags: php, html

I am making a comments system in which i can accept user input **with** line breaks.
I don't want to show the `\n` or `\r` thing
Please help me with this

Comment: none of these is working
i am outputting it into an <li>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nl2br($string);
```

is fast and easy

Comment: nl2br is not working
it shows me the /n thing and doesn't even leave the line

Comment: `nl2br` from manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

They are enabled by default. If you are outputting the text to a web browser, make sure to use [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) or the [white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space) attribute in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**\n** should do the trick.

if you are trying to output a textarea, then use **nl2br();**

also:-

If you are trying to format your HTML source, you should use the constant PHP_EOL. The main reason being that on windows machines the EOL is \r\n and on UNIX machines it is \n. With a properly installed LAMP set up just use PHP_EOL like so.

```
$html.="<p>This is my HTML</p>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

simply replace it

```
preg_replace('/\n/'," ",$str);
```

Comment: I don't understand how this "enables" line breaks. It removes them.

Comment: @Tomalak:yes your are right OP needs to replace the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks will be stored just like any other character.

`\n` is an escape code that allows you to explicitly insert a line break into a string, but I don't think that it's relevant here.

The issue you're *actually* facing is that HTML does not impart any visual meaning to a line break. Line breaks within HTML code do *not*, under normal circumstances, equate to a line break on the screen.

One way to render a line break in HTML is to use a line break tag, or `<br>`.

In PHP, you can automatically convert line breaks to `<br>` with the [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. Applying this to your comment text when you output it into HTML will enable you and other visitors to see the line break visually.